# Magento2 catch ajax complete, add to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax, jquery, mini-cart

I'm building an custom mini-cart. I want it to update itself when an article is added to the cart. I'm trying to do this by jQuery with catching the ajax complete, but can't get it to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Magento 2 add to cart is out of the box ajax call. What do you need?

Comment: Okay I understood your question. Pleae do check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To implement this you must override or extend the core `catalog-add-to-cart.js` file from your module. I assume that you know how to [create a module](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/). Create `requirejs-config.js` file at `/var/www/html/YOURMAGENTOSTORE/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'catalogAddToCart':
                'Vendor_Moduel/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
        }
    }
};
```

Now copy the core file from `Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js` to your file at `/var/www/html/YOURMAGENTOSTORE/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`. Now the part of your interest will be the function named **`ajaxSubmit`**.

```
ajaxSubmit: function(form) {
    var self = this;
    $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');
    self.disableAddToCartButton(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
            }
        },
        success: function(res) {
            if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
            }

            if (res.backUrl) {
                window.location = res.backUrl;
                return;
            }
            if (res.messages) {
                $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
            }
            if (res.minicart) {
                $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
            }
            if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                    .removeClass('available')
                    .addClass('unavailable')
                    .find('span')
                    .html(res.product.statusText);
            }
            console.log('yes added my code');

            self.enableAddToCartButton(form);

        }
    });
},
```

**You need to do whatever you want at the success section of it.**

The **output** of my console is:

**yes added my code**

As you can see that you will be able to catch the ajax success event by this method.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I found another solution that I added via a module block.
This script catches ajax complete for "add to cart" and reads the data returned, like subtotal aso.

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url.indexOf("customer/section/load/?sections=cart") > 0) {
      cartObj = xhr.responseJSON;
      console.log(cartObj);
      console.log('ex tax: ' + cartObj.cart.subtotal_excl_tax);
      console.log('inc tax: ' + cartObj.cart.subtotal_incl_tax);
      console.log('subtotal: ' + cartObj.cart.subtotal);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I do not know about this solution, It seems more like general ajax catcher, but doing my recommended way is how done usually in magento. But this is a good solution as well.

Comment: IMO this is the way better solution than overriding a code file. If one overrides a core file they have to update the file after each Magento update.