# Magento2 : How to create a basic progress bar with ajax, when I click on add to cart button?

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, jquery

I try to make a basic progress bar with ajax , when I click button add to cart, but I don't know how catch the xhr on console,to put on `alert()` or `prepend()`function

> I follow a video example in youtube, with `XMLHttpRequest()` function but I see doesn't work

see the code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', ProgressHandler ,false);
xhr.addEventListener('load', CompleteHandler,false);
xhr.addEventListener('error', errorHandler,false);
xhr.addEventListener('abort',LoadHandler,false);


xhr.open("POST","/test/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzQ1Ljc5LjE0Ni4yMS90ZXN0L3Rlc3RpbmcuaHRtbA%2C%2C/product/1/");
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Please follow this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208384/magento2-catch-ajax-complete-add-to-cart